# How to call function from certain trait explicitly?

Tags: rust

I'd like to know how to call a function from a trait providing that there are several traits with the same function names.

The problem is in the 33 line or
`tr1::tr(v);`

How I have to express which trait I want to call?

```
struct V2D {
  x: i32,
  y: i32
}

impl V2D {
  fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> V2D {
    V2D { x, y }
  }
}

trait tr1 {
  fn tr();
}

trait tr2 {
  fn tr();
}

impl tr1 for V2D {
  fn tr() {
    println!("This is tr1");
  }
}

impl tr2 for V2D {
  fn tr() {
    println!("This is tr2");
  }
}

fn main() {
  let v = V2D::new(1,2);
  tr1::tr(v);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you have used (`tr1::tr(v)`) would be correct if your method took has a `self` parameter ([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de0745db54caa5a5aeeefc24c9ae22dd)), but if it doesn't, you need to call it on the type specifying the type and trait explicitly:

```
<V2D as tr1>::tr()
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a30058bc18c323a3792ed361f0b598cd))

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be using [fully qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name). In your case `tr` is an associated function so all you need is a little typecasting:

```rust
fn main() {
  let v = V2D::new(1,2);
  <V2D as tr1>::tr();
  <V2D as tr2>::tr();
}
```

The syntax for methods on the other hand would be something like this:

```rust
struct V2D {
  x: i32,
  y: i32
}

impl V2D {
  fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> V2D {
    V2D{x,y}
  }
}

trait tr1 {
  fn tr(&self);
}

trait tr2 {
  fn tr(&self);
}

impl tr1 for V2D {
  fn tr(&self) {
    println!("This is tr1");
  }
}
impl tr2 for V2D {
  fn tr(&self) {
    println!("This is tr2");
  }
}

fn main() {
  let v = V2D::new(1,2);
  tr1::tr(&v);
}
```